# How To Login A Custom User In Django

Tags: python, django

Hello This is my models of user app in django,

```py
class Customer(AbstractUser):
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False,) # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser
    groups = None
    user_permissions = None

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Supplier(AbstractUser):
    address = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    phoneNo = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False,) # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser
    groups = None
    user_permissions = None
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

for which i want to implement a login page, i successfully did a signup page using forms

```py
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = Customer
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('phoneNumber',)
        


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields

class CustomSupplierCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = Supplier
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('address','phoneNo',)
        


class CustomSupplierChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Supplier
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields
```

then used

```py
class SignUpPage(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
class SupplierSignUpPage(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomSupplierCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'supplier_signup.html'
```

but i am totally lost as how to implement the login stuff as the doc and google search was overwhelming for me, please help.

Comment: Check this link [how-to-log-a-user-in-1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in-1)

Comment: I did read that but that dosent work for me, please can you elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to add a save method in your `CustomUserCreationForm` class.
   Refer link [django-can-i-use-createview-to-create-a-user-object-where-user-is-just-django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63022695/django-can-i-use-createview-to-create-a-user-object-where-user-is-just-django)

```
def save( self, commit = True ) :
  # Save the provided password in hashed format
  user = super( AccountCreationForm, self ).save( commit = False )
  user.set_password( self.cleaned_data[ "password1" ] )
  if commit:
    user.save()
  return user
```

2. You just have to override form_valid() in your class Inheriting CreateView. Here is the example with my own class.
   Refer [django-how-to-login-user-directly-after-registration-using-generic-createview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510242/django-how-to-login-user-directly-after-registration-using-generic-createview)

```
def form_valid(self, form):
  valid = super(CreateArtistView, self).form_valid(form)
  username, password = form.cleaned_data.get('username'), form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
  new_user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
  login(self.request, new_user)
  return valid
```